# How do I add a new custom post format?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, post-formats

How do I add a new custom format while making a post in WordPress?
The default formats are standard, aside, image, gallery... I want to add a new format of 'xyz' name. How can I do it?

Answer (score 10):

> New formats **cannot** be introduced by themes or even plugins.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Formats

Answer (score 3):

Wordpress currently supports only few post formats, you can have a look at all [Supported Post Format](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Formats#Supported_Formats) on codex. If you are looking for format which in not mentioned there, you will have to use the categories or tags conditions to customize the look for that posts.

Answer (score 0):

As of May 2013, [Post Formats are being pulled from the basic core download](http://make.wordpress.org/core/2013/05/29/post-formats-ui-is-exiting-core-will-live-as-a-plugin/). You might check out a plugin although I've searched for one and haven't seen one. I know Alex King has an older one from 2011.

Answer (score -1):

Either use the current post formats, and make custom template for them.  Or, make custom post types, but, switching post types seems to be a huge pain in the ass.