# How to make the 'delete' button inactive on some categories?

Tags: categories, filters, post-formats, customization

As [currently there's no way](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/65603/22728) to declare any new custom post format in WordPress (3.9.1), is there a way I can make the 'delete' button on some categories inactive, so that the Editor can't remove them, and I can call them where necessary with their IDs without any hustle.
[image: delete button in categories]

I just want it for some specific Categories only — not for all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress uses the `WP_List_Table` class, or some extension of it, to generate those lists. In this case, it is the `WP_Terms_List_Table` class. That class contains a filter called [`{$taxonomy}_row_actions`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.1/src/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-terms-list-table.php#L326).

```
add_filter(
  'category_row_actions',
  function($actions, $tag) {
    $no_del = array(11,22,33);
    if (in_array($tag->term_id,$no_del)) {
      unset($actions['delete']);
    }
    return $actions;
  },
  10,2
);
```

Comment: Thank you @s_ha_dum. I thought I could go with something like `current_user_can('editor')` and to target any capability like `delete_categories` (not exists) etc. But the solution is totally in a different place. Thanks a lot for the insights.